# Bundle identifier on iOS paths?

Tags: ios, file

I have seen the Apple documentation use bundle identifier appended to the Application Support directory for getting a usable path and I see similar approaches in some libraries too.

Doesn't every application has it's private sandboxed support directory? If so, why we are encouraged to append bundle identifier to paths? Is it about shared data between applications?

Please enlight me on this as I could not get a sound answer to my question anywhere else and this keeps bugging me.

Comment: I've never seen what you are talking about. Each app does have its own unique sandbox folder and its "Application Support" folder is inside of it. There's no point to appending yet another folder inside of it.

Comment: @rmaddy Please see the listing 2-1 in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW7

Comment: OK, there's no point. I think they are just showing an example of how to get the AppSupport folder and how to add a folder to that. But in practice there is no reason that I know of for adding the bundle id to the path.

Comment: @rmaddy I have seen libraries like LogKit  use this convention too. Maybe it is related to shared data in application groups, etc. But I could not see a real explanation in Apple documents.